# Binding from an XAML resource dictionary to a class property

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, resources, properties

I am having a very difficult time setting up a binding which I think should be easy.  Help is greatly appreciated.

I have a resource dictionary named FormResource.xaml.  In this dictionary contains a Style for the ScrollView that I redine the template for.  The purpose is I want a wider vertical scrollbar on it.

```
<Style x:Key="LargeScrolling" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="ScrollContentPresenter"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" 
                            Style="{StaticResource LargeVerticalScrollBar}" 
                            Width="{Binding ElementName=MDTForm, Path=ScrollBarWidth}"
                            IsTabStop="False"
                            Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                            Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical"
                            ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                            Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                            Minimum="0"
                            Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                            Margin="0,-1,-1,-1"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I have a UserControl named FormControl.

```
public class FormControl : UserControl
```

I used to have this as a partial class with a XAML componenet, in which what I am trying to do worked, but I had to remove the XAML since I derive from this class in another assembly and WPF does not allow you to derive from a partial class in another assembly.

In FormControl I define a ScrollBarWidth property.

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollBarWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ScrollBarWidth", typeof(double), typeof(FormControl));
    public double ScrollBarWidth
    {
        get { return (double)base.GetValue(ScrollBarWidthProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(ScrollBarWidthProperty, value); }
    }
```

When I had this as a partial class in the main declaration I gave the FormControl class a Name of MDTForm, which is what I am using as the ElementName in my binding.  I tried registering this name in FormClass.cs but no matter what I do the scrollbar is not picking up the property value.

Here is where I create my ScrollViewer in the FormControl class.

```
        _canvasScrollViewer = new ScrollViewer();
        _canvasScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
        _canvasScrollViewer.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        _canvasScrollViewer.MaxHeight = Constants.ScrollViewMaxHeight;
        _canvasScrollViewer.Style = (Style)FindResource("LargeScrolling");
```

The only way that I got this to work was to bind to a static property.  I used this for the binding.

```
Width="{Binding Source={x:Static form:FormControl.ScrollBarWidthP}}"
```

Then defined the property as such.

```
public static double ScrollBarWidth { get; set; }
```

However, I don't want this as I can have multiple FormControl objects loaded at the same time and they may not all have the same scroll bar width property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a RelativeSource Binding instead of ElementName:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
         AncestorType={x:Type controls:FormControl}}, Path=ScrollBarWidth}
```

This will walk up the visual tree at runtime to find the parent control containing the ScrollViewer, which solves both your scoping and multiple instance issues.

Comment: Thank you, that is awesome and works perfectly.  Would it be possible to have it support an automatic property instead of the DependancyProperty?  It only needs to be a one way binding, the ScrollViewer will never update the property of the FormControl class.  It works now, which is great, but I would prefer to not have to use the DependancyProperty if possible.

Comment: It only needs to be a DP if you're assigning a Binding to it (in this case Width) but not on the other side - this is true for TwoWay Bindings as well. ScrollBarWidth in this case could be either a DP, a property using INotifyPropertyChanged (if updates to it need to show up on Width), or just any normal property if no updating is needed.

Comment: When I changed it to just be a class property defined at public double ScrollBarWidth { get; set; } it doesn't work.  I didn't change anything will the Binding statement, so perhaps a change there is required.